# How to set default root algorithm to sha512 on Linux?

Tags: password, pam, hashsum

I can see the content below in `/etc/shadow`. The root password's hash algorithm is md5, but the test user's is sha512:

```
root:$1$RjnJa1j6$.HbXUfxVzGSSAgSvz52Zm1:19251:0:99999:7:::
.
.
.
test:$6$6myiVypQtv/A31gF$totJgATLtEnHGHNuDdgRDVyhAOoI3s1xYQ5Cw1DqhjQ4UKC.brqRGSP/GMJ.KpZ079Rqm6KaPG6IhoiwocELY1:0:0:99999:7:::
```

I've checked the settings in `/etc/login.defs`:

```
ENCRYPT_METHOD SHA512
```

and `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`:

```
password sufficient pam_unix.so nullok sha512 shadow try_first_pass try_authtok
```

In both files, the algorithm is set to sha512, so why is root's md5?

Is it possible to set root's default password hashing algorithm to be sha512 without using the `passwd` command?

Thanks!

Comment: there is no way to convert the password from one hash to the other hash.  a new hash will need to be generated for the root account.  `passwd` is the most convenient way to generate a hash,

Comment: Thank you for all your comment, it is really helpful. and I use passwd to set a new sha512 password.

Answer (score 2):

With high probability the answer of first question is - legacy system. Old system, updated several times, the original use `md5`, current version use `sha` so the update procedure do not change the passwords because (see below paragraph).

You can't convert one hash in another because by definition hash is one way encryption. So you do not know the plain text (when encrypt password is used also salt) so you can't (easy) create hash of `root` password.

As mentioned in comment: use `passwd`

Answer (score 0):

> Is possible to set root default password to algorithm sha512 without using passwd command?

It is possible in theory to "convert" hashes by daisy-chaining them.

So you would store a new hash of the old hash; but at that point you are storing the new hash without knowing the original plaintext password. So in order to validate a given password, instead of checking the password against the new hash directly, you'd have to calculate the old hash first, then check the old hash against the new hash.

Some web apps used such a method when they had to migrate away from unsalted md5 hashes any way they could. Considering they have lots of users who don't login again for years, if ever, and also can't be reached by their (often outdated) mail addresses.

So in theory it would be possible to implement the same thing for user passwords but - I don't know if it exists anywhere. It's a bit esoteric and not really worth it.

Just set a new password. You get a new hash/salt every time you set one, even if the plaintext password stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

> How to set default root algorithm to sha512 on Linux?

On one hand I believe this may be linux distribution specific, more importantly the version.  According to google, SHA512 was introduced in 2001.  My question would be what linux distro and version are you using?  Because in RHEL 7.9 my root password is *SHA512'd* just like all my user accounts.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/login.defs.5.html

> ENCRYPT_METHOD - This only affect the generation of group passwords. The
> generation of user passwords is done by PAM and subject to
> the PAM configuration. It is recommended to set this variable
> consistently with the PAM configuration.

> MD5_CRYPT_ENAB - This variable is deprecated. You should use ENCRYPT_METHOD.  *Most likely deprecated if you're running a modern linux distro.*

On the other hand, if you are running a modern linux distro and your root password is MD5 hashed per the `$1$` id in `/etc/shadow` when other passwords are SHA512 per the `$6` id, that is a security red flag.

The setting of `sha512` in `pam.d` to tell the `passwd` command what subsequent hash to generate is completely independent of the hashes that are currently existing in `/etc/shadow`.  Anyone with the permission to do so can make it so the root password or any other has any kind of hash currently not specified by the pam `system-auth` and `password-auth`

you should basically make sure your `login.defs` and `pam.d` files specify SHA512 along with seeing all `$6$` in `/etc/shadow`.